# additional settings.plist not display in Settings Bundle in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, settings.bundle

in the last hours i try to implement an additional Settings Bundle plist file. 
On this screen you can see on the left site the Root.plist with the ChildNode item for the additional plist file called "more.plist" (which is located within the settings.bundle in xCode.
[image: xCode Screenshot with both plist files]

But when i deploy the app to the simulator i cannot see the additional settings pane "Third Party Licenses". 
[image]

When i click "Third Party Licenses" there comes an empty page.

[image: the result]

Whats wrong ? And yes, i have read the developer library @ apple dev center but i could not find the information that i am searching for :(

I am grateful for ideas !

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall your app and then reinstall, it worked for me...